# How to remove or reduce the white space between the header and the page title Astra WP theme

Tags: css, wordpress

Never used CSS before and was pleased to find how to change the header color, it worked great.

Now trying to remove or at least reduce the white space between the page title and the header(?) where my logo is.
Read the similar question but the suggestions didn't work for me.

I also want to make the PAGE TITLE itself smaller as it looks too big on a mobile phone, have tried pasting various bits of code that I've found in searches but nothing has worked.

I'm in my 60s and am not very techy so please be gentle :)

Many thanks in advance,

My site is: [www.andypiggott.com](http://www.andypiggott.com) (Astra theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to head over to the Appearance » Customize page from your WordPress dashboard, The tab will slide to show you a simple box where you can add your custom CSS, now add this code:

```
.ast-plain-container.ast-no-sidebar #primary {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

For page title you can paste this code :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .entry-title {
   font-size:20px;
//or what ever the font size you want to be on mobile 
  }
}
```